# Max number of maxclients en serverlimit on IBM Bluemix php instance

Tags: php, instance, ibm-cloud

I have a php instance in IBM Bluemix. Now I had problems with multiple connections to the php instance.
I increase the maxclients en serverlimit both to 256.

My questions is, what is the maximum number of maxcliensts en serverlimits for a IBM bluemix PHP instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a predefined limit on Bluemix runtimes, it usually depends from the buildpack configuration: according to the buildpack used you can set this kind of parameters through custom configuration files for PHP (php.ini), APACHE (httpd.conf and so on), nginx (nginx[...].conf) where you could set all the parameters you wish to modify from the default values provided by the buildpack you are using

Using the standard php buildpack available from cloudFoundry you can follow the instructions you find here

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/docs/config.md

to edit a lot of configuration values

- For APACHE settings (if you use APACHE) you could provide your custom conf (one or more) to integrate default values
- For nginx settings (if you use nginx) you could provide your custom conf (one or more) to integrate default values like Apache
- For PHP settings you could provide your custom php.ini: it should be put in .bp-config/php/[php version]/php.ini

The default values are under 
php-buildpack/defaults
where you can find all the default settings

In your specific case, wishing to edit your max connections accepted you have to edit the following values:

- if you use Apache, in the httpd/extra/httpd-mpm.conf file you have to add the MaxClients parameter (default to 256 for Apache) in mpm_worker_module
- if you use nginx the parameter to edit should be worker_connections in nginx/nginx-workers.conf

So basically you could take these default files, edit according to your need, put the file in your config directory
.bp-config/apache/extra/ for Apache
.bp-config/nginx/ for nginx
and push it along with your application

Ps.: to set your HTTPD to APACHE or nginx you have to set it through 
.bp-config/options.json
setting the value of WEB_SERVER to Apache or nginx

Anyway on the buildpack documentation linked above you have all the configuration options you could set through your custom configuration files and how to add these.

Comment: So if I got it clear I can set both values to for example 1024 ?

Comment: I edited my response adding more details, the max connections parameter has to be set on the Apache server or nginx configuration